# Kivy: Add ScreenManager to window not as root?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using Kivy and I'm trying to setup a ScreenManager, but I don't want that ScreenManager to be the root widget in my window. Here's a test code snippet that demonstrates what I'm trying to do. (This code demonstrates my problem.)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyRootWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyRootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        self.add_widget(self.screen_manager)

        # self.add_widget(Label(text='label direct'))


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root = MyRootWidget()

        new_screen = Screen(name='foo')
        new_screen.add_widget(Label(text='foo screen'))
        root.screen_manager.add_widget(new_screen)
        root.screen_manager.current = 'foo'

        for x in root.walk():
            print x

        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

When I run this code, the window is blank, though I would expect that it would show the text "foo screen"?

The print of the `walk()` command shows that the root widget contains the screenmanager, my screen, and the label, like this:

```
<__main__.MyRootWidget object at 0x109d59c80>
<kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager object at 0x109eb4ae0>
<Screen name='foo'>
<kivy.uix.label.Label object at 0x109ecd390>
```

So that's working as I would expect.

If I uncomment the line which adds the label widget directly to the root widget, that label shows up as expected.

Also if I change the `MyApp.build()` method so that it returns `new_screen` instead of returning `root`, it also works in that I see the label "foo screen" on the display.

BTW, the reason I want to not have the screen manager be the root widget is because I want to be able to print messages (almost like popups) on the screen in front of whichever screen is active (even if screens are in the process of transitioning), so I was thinking I would need the screen manager not to be root in order to do that?

Also my ultimate goal is to have multiple "quadrants" in the window, each with its own screen manager, so I was thinking I needed to make sure I can show screen managers that are not the root widget in order to do this.

So if there's a better way for me to do this, please let me know. Also I do not want to use .kv files for this as I want to set this entire environment up programmatically based on other config options (which I've left out of this example.)

Overall though I wonder if anyone knows why this code doesn't work?

Thanks!
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are sticking your `ScreenManager` in a generic `Widget`.  If you put it in a Layout, it will display properly, ie:

```
class MyRootWidget(BoxLayout):
```

There are several layouts available: http://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/layouts.html